# fading frames in and out

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a set of frames that I need to show in a sequence one after the other but instead of simply erasing the previous frame and drawing the next one, I need to fade out the previous frame and fade in the new one simultaneously.

What is the best way to achieve this in cocos2d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void) showFirstSpriteWithFade
{
    if( [m_sprites count] > 0 )
    {
        CCSprite* spriteToShow = [m_sprites objectAtIndex: 0];
        [m_sprites removeObjectAtIndex: 0];

        id showAction = [CCSequence actions: [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration: fadeInDuration],
                                             [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration: fadeOutDuration],
                                             [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget: self selector:@selector(showFirstSpriteWithFade)],
                                             nil];
       [spriteToShow runAction: showAction];
    }
}
```

this will work if you wil store all your sprites in array m_sprites. in this case all sprites must be added to the parent to be shown one by one. you can improve this code if you want, for example, use just one sprite and change it's texture each time.

if you wanna show pictures forever, you can try something like this

```
- (void) showNextSpriteWithFade
{
        m_shownSpriteIndex++;
        if( m_shownSpriteIndex == [m_sprites count] )
        {
            m_shownSpriteIndex = 0;
        }

        CCSprite* spriteToShow = [m_sprites objectAtIndex: m_shownSpriteIndex];

        id showAction = [CCSequence actions: [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration: fadeInDuration],
                                             [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration: fadeOutDuration],
                                             [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget: self selector:@selector(showNextSpriteWithFade)],
                                             nil];
       [spriteToShow runAction: showAction];

}
```

Comment: thanks. I am new to cocos2d, so I am not sure, in this code the subsequent calls to showFirstSpriteWithFade are done recursively, correct? which means that if I want to do this forever, it won't work.

Comment: You didn't mention that you wanna do this forever. You can store index of currently shown sprite. In this case at the beginning of this method you can increment this index and set to 0 if it will be more than sprites count after increment. And, of course, in this case you must not remove shown sprites from array

Comment: yes, my question is about recursion, I realise that I do not need to remove the sprites from the array, but if the method is called recursively in an infinite loop it will run out of stack space eventually and crash.

Comment: it is not recursion. in this case method just use itself as callback

Comment: Would you explain this? yes, it uses itself as a callback. the method runs the sequence action and at the end of the sequence it calls the callback, which happens to be the same method. this is a recursion in my understanding. BTW, thanks for your help, I appreciate it. I was thinking to use schedule method or scheduleUpdate, but I am going to try this approach first.

Comment: recursion means that method calls itself inside it. in this case method just runs sequence of actions and program continue it's work. when fadeIn and fadeOut finished, this method will be called again.

Comment: in other words runAction is not blocking, it returns immediately and it does not wait for the action to complete. instead, the action is run by the director (?), or whatever entity does the scheduling, correct?

Comment: all actions are managed by CCActionManager singleton. and yep - runAction returns immediately.